# Line numbering outside a box

Tags: line-numbering

I have problems getting a line numbering similar to that in the picture.

[image: what the numbering should look like]

I created the box with `\frambox{\parbox{` but with the command `\linenumbers` I only get the whole box numbered with a 1.

I would appreciate it if somebody could post me a fitting code.

Best
Felix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `\internallinenumbers` command from the `lineno` package.

---

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

    \fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{\internallinenumbers
        \kant[1]}}

\end{document}
```

The code produces this:

[image: output]